# Did Angular 2 have somethings like event when before and after Route's resolver

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to change Route and loading some data with Resolver, Can I show some loading component until resolve is done and show Component. It have something like before-resolve, after-resolve or not ?

Comment: Showing some actual code is usually a good idea with SO questions.

Comment: I didn't write it yet. but I see NavigationStart, NavigationEnd that the way to do but I want to know alternative ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the power of observables(To know more about it google it and read about it first)**

**Create a loading component**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import { LoadingService } from "./loadindicator.service";
import { StatsOverviewPage} from "./page.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'loading-indicator',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
       <div [style.visibility]="isLoading ? 'visible': 'hidden'" class="loading-indicator-container">           
            <img src="/images/loading.gif" />
       </div>
      `,
})
export class LoadingIndicator implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private isLoading = false;
    private subscription: any;

    //we probably want a reference to ElementRef here to do some DOM manipulations
    constructor(public el: ElementRef, public loadingService: LoadingService) { }

    showOrHideLoadingIndicator(loading) {
        this.isLoading = loading;
        if (this.isLoading) this.playLoadingAnimation();
        //else cancel the animation?
    }

    playLoadingAnimation() {
        //this will be your implementation to start the loading animation
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.loadingService.loading$.subscribe(loading => { this.showOrHideLoadingIndicator(loading) });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Then create a service which will be used by other component to load the above components

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Observer} from "rxjs/Observer";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

/**
 * Singleton service, injected at app level
 */
export class LoadingService {
    loading$: Observable<String>;
    private _observer: Observer<String>;

    constructor() {
        this.loading$ = new Observable<String>(
            observer => this._observer = observer);
    }

    toggleLoadingIndicator(name) {
        if (this._observer) {
            this._observer.next(name);
        }
    }
}
```

now whenever you need to show the loader just call the toggleLoadingIndicator function of the service by passing true and when your action has been completed just pass false value to the same function

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
//import {StatsService} from "../../services/stats-service";
import {LoadingIndicator} from "./loading.component";
import { LoadingService } from "./loadindicator.service";


@Component({
    templateUrl: "/app/LoadingIndicator/loading.html", 
    directives: [LoadingIndicator]
})
export class StatsOverviewPage {
    isShow: boolean = false;
    private stats: Array<any> = [];

    constructor( private loadingService: LoadingService) { }

    onPageLoaded(): void {
        //this.isShow = !isShow
        this.loadingService.toggleLoadingIndicator(true);

        //this.loadingService.toggleLoadingIndicator(this.isShow);
        //setTimeout(2000);
        this.getDataSlowly().then(response => {

            this.loadingService.toggleLoadingIndicator(false);
        });

    }
    getDataSlowly() {

        return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 2000));
         // 2 seconds
    }
}
```